# Android start a service every 5 seconds

Tags: android

I want to make a finite State Machine first calling my `StartEstablishService()` method every 5 seconds so that the app will try to reconnect to the service once the service fails. When the service fails it will destroy the service and the only thing I need to do the to call the `StartEstablishService()` method again and this is the output after connection failed :`Destroying service...Service destroyed`

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroying service...");
    t.interrupt();
    Log.d(TAG, "Service destroyed.");

}
```

How do I call  the `StartEstablishService()` every 5 seconds? I tried to call the following method after the service is destroyed

```
public void startExploring() {
        Log.e(TAG,"Start Exploring Every 8 Seconds...");
        final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;
        final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.startData();
                handler.postDelayed(this,
                FIVE_SECONDS);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

but it the activity is always null??

Comment: Are you making a `Fragment` or an `Activity` ? If it's a fragment, capture the activity in the `onActivityCreated()` callback, otherwise capture it in the `onCreate()` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [alarm manager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) for starting service every 5 minutes.

For finding why activity is null,you have to post more code including filename,structure you used etc